# open не работает с os.path.sameopenfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Этот код

```
import os
o=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt')
o2=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt')
print(os.path.sameopenfile(o,o2))
```

Выдаёт

```
File "C:\Users\user\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 109, in sameopenfile
    s1 = os.fstat(fp1)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [os.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) вместо [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
import os
o1 = os.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
o2 = os.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
print(os.path.sameopenfile(o1, o2))
```

Comment: @importpynoob  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

```
print(os.path.sameopenfile(o.fileno(), o2.fileno()))
```